# Accessibility screen reader reading number with trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I'm working on making a '-' read as 'to' for a screen reader when reading an amount range.

I got it working using a screen reader only class, hiding the original text and writing what i want the screen reader to read in anther screen reader only span.

```
.sr-only {
border: 0 !important;
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
-webkit-clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
height: 1px !important;
margin: -1px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
padding: 0 !important;
position: absolute !important;
width: 1px !important;
white-space: nowrap !important;
```

}

```
       "Here is an amounts range <span aria-hidden='true'>{formattedMinAmount}-{formattedMaxAmount}.</span><span class='sr-only'>{formattedMinAmount} to {formattedMaxAmount}</span>"
```

However, the screen reader reads the formattedMinAmount and formattedMaxAmount as
299.00 to 6,000.00 with .00 at the end. I want to have it read as 299 to 6,000.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before. It only reads the .00 with the spans added for screen reader only and I can't figure out why. I'd love some help with this.

Comment: I tend to believe that there is no problem here at all. To non screen reader users, it might sometimes seem weird how certain texts are read, but their users are used to it and we as web developers shouldn’t mess with it. But have you tried using [the typographically corret en dash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Ranges_of_values) instead of a minus? What is the screen reader reading then?

Comment: Also, what you call `sr-only` is not only for screen readers, Braille displays will also use this text, and those users—once again—are more used to dashes than the word “to”.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a screen reader reads the '-' is fine. It's a normal way that numbers are written, and screen reader users will be used to it. Unless you had a specific screen reader user requesting this, I wouldn't recommend trying to get the screen reader to say different words for the dash.

As far as getting rid of the ".00" - I only see that happen when that text is present. What exactly is the text that you have in the "sr-only" element?

Also, if browsers and screen readers started supporting this aria attribute, it might be helpful for you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-valuetext

Comment: As far as I know `aria-valuetext` is reasonably well supported - but only for the roles it applies to (listed in the MDN docs you link to). It's not supposed to be used for generic elements like a `span` so no wonder it's not well-supported for that.